# como executar cálculos entre 4 input, ao carregar pagina ou alterar valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 4 campos input, sendo:

1. Custo que já vem com um valor no value
2. O campo frete, que ao ser alterado o valor deve ser somado com o custo e exibido no total
3. O campo desconto, que ao ser alterado o valor deve subtrair do total

Bom não sei como fazer isso.

Segue o código com os input.

```html
Custo
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' $input_total id='total_pedido' name='total_pedido' readonly='true' value='5.000,30'>

<br>
Frete
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='encargos' name='encargos'>

<br>
Desconto
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='desconto' name='desconto'>

<br>
Total
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc2' id='total_val' name='total_val'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu HTML deve ser alterado. Adicionar a propriedade `onkeyup` aos campos `encargos` e `desconto`.

```
Custo
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' $input_total id='total_pedido' name='total_pedido' readonly='true' value='5.000,35' id="total_pedido">
<br>
Frete
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='encargos' name='encargos' onkeyup='calcular()'>
<br>
Desconto
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='desconto' name='desconto' onkeyup='calcular()'>
<br>
Total
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc2' id='total_val' name='total_val'>
```

A seguir é preciso definir a função `calcular`:

```
//É necessário verificar se o campo "total_pedido" já foi renderizado e pode ser referenciado pelo script, 
//por isso é preciso escutar o evento `DOMContentLoaded`.
var total = 0;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    total = document.getElementById("total_pedido").value;
    //Retiramos a formatação do campo e convertemos em uma string
    total = Number(total.replace(/[.]+/g,"").replace(",","."));
    //A função é executada para preencher o campo com o valor total
    calcular();
});

function calcular() {
    //Obtemos o valor do encargo e desconto
    var encargos = Number(document.getElementById("encargos").value);
    var desconto = Number(document.getElementById("desconto").value);
    var t = total + encargos - desconto;
    //Atualizamos o campo "total_val" com o valor total
    document.getElementById("total_val").value = t.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
}
```

Veja em funcionamento aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/kmjr5atg/9/

Comment: perfeito, so tem mais duas coisas. notei que para executar tenho que colocar um valor no frete ou desconto, tem com executar mesmo eles estando em branco? ou seja ja carregar a pagina executando. 2º e possível escrever o valor total no padrão 1.000,00?

Comment: @HugoBorges, sim, tem. Alterei a resposta, veja se é o pretendido.

Comment: @HugoBorges adicionei o valor formatado no exemplo da resposta, veja funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/kmjr5atg/4/

Comment: é isso mesmo, porém ao invés de aparecer o R$ no total eu preciso do valor apenas formatado em pt-br 1.000,00.

Comment: @HugoBorges basta então remover a string "RS" no código acima. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: mas ele não fica formatado no padrão 1.000,00

Comment: @HugoBorges basta alterar a linha onde temos `document.getElementById("total_val").value = t;` para `document.getElementById("total_val").value = t.toLocaleString();`.  Veja, eu postei na resposta essa opção.

Comment: amigo desculpa minha ignorância hahahah mas não funcionou comigo. O número do total esta assim: 5022.35 e preciso que ele fique assim: 5.022,35

Comment: @HugoBorges mas está assim, reveja a resposta que dei e veja aqui o código que postei acima funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/kmjr5atg/9/

Comment: estranho, aqui realmente não esta funcionando. da uma olhada neste print que eu tirei. http://s11.postimg.org/ykhnwg6qb/Captura_de_Tela_2016_02_24_s_13_14_19.png Repara que o valar não esta formatado com o . e ,

Comment: amigo notei que o erro so ocorre no safari, estranho. Mas de qualquer forma muito obrigado pela solução. So mais uma dúvida, e possível fazer com que ao se alterar o total_val o sistema informa o desconto?

Comment: @HugoBorges tem sim, veja aqui a funcionar: https://jsfiddle.net/kmjr5atg/11/

Comment: muito bom, agora tem como passar o desconto para %. ai ira ficar tudo 100% :)

Answer (score 2):

Explicando o código abaixo;

1. Através do `ID`, capturamos as referências dos inputs do `HTML`;
2. Adicionamos um evento para os elementos `desconto` e `frete`, de modo
   que estes irão executar a função `calcular()` sempre que uma tecla
   pressionada for liberada;
3. Definimos a função `calcular`, que transforma os valores dos inputs em
   números através do construtor `Number` e realiza o cálculo `(total =
   custo + frete - desconto)`;
4. Por fim, atribuímos ao `value` do elemento `total` o cálculo realizado,
   formatando sua apresentação para `'pt-BR'` com o método `toLocaleString`

```js
var frete = document.getElementById("encargos");
var desconto = document.getElementById("desconto");
var total = document.getElementById("total_val");
var custo = document.getElementById("total_pedido");

/*Criando eventos para executarem a função calcular sempre que uma tecla for pressionada*/
desconto.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  calcular();
});

frete.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  calcular();
});

/*Função calcular; converte os valores dos inputs para float e então calcula (total = custo + frete - desconto)*/
function calcular() {
  var valorTotal = Number(custo.value) + Number(frete.value) - Number(desconto.value);
  total.value = valorTotal.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
}
```

```html
Custo
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' $input_total id='total_pedido' name='total_pedido' readonly='true' value='5000.30'>

<br>Frete
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='encargos' name='encargos'>

<br>Desconto
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc' id='desconto' name='desconto'>

<br>Total
<input type='text' class='form_campos calc2' id='total_val' name='total_val'>
```

**Referências**

- [Eventos em javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)
- [Number constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)
- [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: ok, porém tem algumas coisa que precisa ser alteradas. notei que o so funciona se eu informar um valor para frete e desconto, porem preciso que ele funcione se nenhum valor for informado. Tem como?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta, estou sem muito tempo agora. É possível atualizando a função calcular. Sugiro iniciar ambos os campos com valor 0. Também foi necessário formatar o campo custo pois o valor "5.000,03" não pode ser convertido em float sem tratamento antes. Em breve atualizo a resposta com ambas as informações

Comment: ok fico no aguardo

Comment: Código foi atualizado para funcionar apenas com os valores informados

Answer (score -1):

```
    //obtenho o valor dos campos
    var vtotal = $('#total_pedido').val();
    var vfrete = $('#encargos').val();
    var desconto= $('#desconto').val();

    //efetuo o calculo que será exibido no ultimo input
    vtotal = ((vtotal+vfrete)-desconto);
    //escrevo o resultado no ultimo input
    $('#total_val').val(vtotal);

   // lembrando que as tags dessa pergunta mencionam javascript E JQuery
```

Comment: como eu chamo a função no input?

Comment: Poderia explicar o que faz esse código?

Comment: Para chamar a função no input crie uma função javascript com o nome que desejar, utilize o evento do input para chamar a função. Exemplo, se você deseja chamar a função de nome calcular quando o usuario tirar o foco de um input você coloca isso no input  onBlur="javascript:calcular();". Para o amigo que pediu pra eu explicar o que faz a função.  Nas três primeiras linhas eu obtenho o valor dos inputs, na quarta eu efetuo o calculo e escrevo o resultado no ultimo input. Obviamente está faltando o devido tratamento quando há campos nulos, assim como as conversões com parseFloat().